# How to convert a random string to a unique and ID friendly string in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Given many random strings in javasript, for example:

```js
str1 = "1%&2xy 232=2"
str2 = "2$$2xy 232=2"
str3 = "ls dlsdl fs§$02"
```

So the string may contain spaces, numbers, $, %, &, all kinds of chars.

Now let's say I want to generate html elements, one element for each string:

```html
<div id="???">str1</div>
<div id="???">str2</div>
<div id="???">str3</div>
```

How can I add ids to each element that is created by each string itself? Removing unwanted chars won't work because different strings can result in the same ID. I also want to avoid `$('div:contains(str)')` as I'm looking for a way to generate unique and reproducible IDs.

I thought about converting each string to hexadecimal and prepend "a" as IDs can not start with a number.

But does anyone knows a better way to do that?

Comment: Use Base64: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript

Comment: you could try URL encoding

Comment: @David Zimmerman URL encoding does not guarantee ID-compatible strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are restricted to using ids, convert to base64 using `btoa`:

```js
// Prefix with a letter since it is possible for a base64 string to start with a number.
element.id = "i" + btoa(str1); // "1%&2xy 232=2" -> "MSUmMnh5IDIzMj0y"
```

If this is not a requirement, use a `data` attribute instead:

```html
<div data-str="1%&2xy 232=2">str1</div>
<div data-str="2$$2xy 232=2">str2</div>
```